# How to redirect to another page using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to find a way to redirect to another page using javascript once the user presses the submit form. I know how to do it using HTML but I can not get it to work here. The form submits but then it won't take you anywhere. I have tried a couple of different things I found online but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code

```
"use strict";

// global variables
var profile = {};
var formValidity = true

// validate entered password
function validateEmail() {
   var email1Input = document.getElementById("email");
   var email2Input = document.getElementById("email_retype");
   email1Input.value = email1Input.value.toLowerCase();
   email2Input.value = email2Input.value.toLowerCase();
   var errorDiv = document.getElementById("emailError");
   try {
        
        if (email1Input.value.localeCompare(email2Input.value) !== 0) {
            throw "The e-mails do not match";
        }
              // remove any password error styling and message
              email1Input.style.background = "";
              email2Input.style.background = "";
              errorDiv.style.display = "none";
              errorDiv.innerHTML = "";
             
           }
       catch(msg) {
          // display error message
          errorDiv.style.display = "block";
          errorDiv.innerHTML = msg;
          // change input style
          email1Input.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";
          email2Input.style.background = "rgb(255,233,233)";  
          formValidity = false;    
       }
}


 /* create event listeners */
    function createEventListeners(){
        var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
           if (form.addEventListener){
               form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);
           }else if (form.attachEvent) {
               form.attachEvent("onsubmit", validateForm);
           }
       }
   
   /* validate form */
   function validateForm(evt) {
       if(evt.preventDefault) {
           evt.preventDefault(); // prevent form from submitting
        }else {
            evt.returnValue = false; // prevent form from submitting in IE8
        }
        formValidity = true; // reset value for revalidation
        validateEmail();
        if (formValidity === true) {
            document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0].submit();
            location.href = "about.php";
        }
   }
   
    /* run setup functions when page finishes loading */
    if (window.addEventListener) {
        window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);
    }else if (window.attachEvent) {
        window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
    }
```

Comment: i think href should be complete url for example : `https://www.google.com`

Comment: If you want to submit data to a database and then redirect to another  page with only JavaScript, please look up Firebase. I think it is one of the easiest option. Or you can also send data to Google Spreadsheet with GAS ( Google Apps Script). It’s pretty easy too. Otherwise consider using PHP normally:)

Answer (score 0):

You are unable to submit the form and then redirect. because the submit will redirect to the page defined in the form's "action". I see that your javascript function is just validating the fields
Example:

```html
<form action = "action_page.php" method = "get">
```

Comment: I guess what the OP wants to know is not how to submit but only how to redirect to another page when a submit button is pressed :) Actually his/her requirements are a bit ambiguous. So I’m sorry if I’m wrong.

Comment: Miu you are right sorry if I did not explain my question well enough. I would like the submit button to submit the form and then redirect the user to a new page afterward.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Brian N. And I’m sorry, RodeigoKulb.

Answer (score 0):

This should help some... your if statements, such as:

```
if(window.addEventListener){ ... } || if(document.addEventListener){ ... }
```

will not execute the way you are expecting in your current implementation. If you would like to set up your event handlers when the window loads, you'd be better of implementing something like:

```
window.onload = createEventListeners; 

// or

window.onload = function() {
   var form = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
   form.addEventListener("submit", validateForm, false);     
}
```

Here is some documentation on window.onload

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload

and submitting an HTML with examples using javascript event handlers

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event

Although, if you *really* need/want to **manually redirect the user using js**, one way you can achieve this through window.location:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

I normally wouldn't normally recommend redirecting users this way, but I don't know enough about your code entirely, and it's still something that is very good to understand.